# How can I add an user to the Azure SQL database?

Tags: c#, sql, azure

How can I add programmatically a SQL user to the database with the new Azure Sdk?

I can successfully create a database with the following approach:

```
var client = new ArmClient(credential);
var subscription = await client.GetDefaultSubscriptionAsync();       

// Only one server available
var sqlServers = subscription.GetSqlServers().ToList();
var sqlServer = sqlServers.FirstOrDefault();

var data = new SqlDatabaseData(AzureLocation.GermanyWestCentral) {
                Location = "westeurope",
                Sku = new SqlSku("P1") {
                    Name = "Basic",
                    Tier = "Basic",
                },
                Collation = "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS",
                MaxSizeBytes = 1073741824, 
            };

sqlServer.GetSqlDatabases().CreateOrUpdate(WaitUntil.Completed, databaseName, data);
```

Any help would be grateful.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

- I have created **Azure keyvault** and **Azure database** in portal.
- Added secret in keyvault and I have given SQL connection string as a value while creating the secret.

Below is the code that works for me.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace Example
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Initialize Azure credentials
            var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

            // Retrieve the SQL database connection string from Azure Key Vault
            var secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri("https://enter your keyvault name.vault.azure.net/"), credential);
            var connectionString = (await secretClient.GetSecretAsync("secret name")).Value.Value;

            // Connect to the SQL database
            using var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            await connection.OpenAsync();

            // Create a new SQL user with the desired credentials
            var command = new SqlCommand("CREATE USER Admin21 WITH PASSWORD = 'password'", connection);
            await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

            // Close the database connection
            await connection.CloseAsync();

            Console.WriteLine("SQL user created successfully!");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output :**
[image]

I able to connect the created user in database.

[image]

Comment: Thanx, but this is not what I want do to. I would like to use the Azure SDK (C#) and create the completely database and their users. How can I achieve this with Azure.ResourceManager.Sql. I didn't find any information.

Comment: Can you specify in Azure SQL Database, user authentication is handled by SQL Server authentication or Azure AD.